# how to send response using soap handler

Tags: web-services

I am using soap header for authentication process, if the authentication success, remaining processes are completed and got the response. But if authentication fails, i don't know how to send the error response back to client. I used soaphandler to retrieve the header values.

Regards
venu

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sample code here
http://buddhiraju.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/use-soap-message-handler-for-cross-cutting-concerns-caching/

This will give you an idea. You basically can modify the message content is the soap handler.